# How do I fix multiple definition of `_meta'?

Tags: c, linux, git-clone

I cloned buildroot.After giving 'make' command its showing below compiler error.

```
/home/buildroot/instance-0/output/host/usr/bfin-buildroot-uclinux-uclibc/sysroot/usr/lib/libncurses.a(lib_options.o): In function `_meta':
../ncurses/./tinfo/lib_options.c:(.text+0x22c): multiple definition of `_meta'
main.o:main.c:(.text+0xc): first defined here
```

Anybody can help me to solve this error and also give some information about meta.

Answer (score 0):

It is what it is: The function _meta you declared was defined in multiple locations.

You have definition of the function in `lib_options.c` while an earlier definition was made in: `main.c`

If you include `lib_options.c` from the main define it in `lib_options.c` only. That way there will be only one declaration of the function.

Comment: Thank you Anton.P.                                               Both .c files are in different packages.so After include lib_options.c from main its giving below error---                                            main.c:63:27: error: lib_options.c: No such file or directory..